# How to insert INLINE text box in html

Tags: html

Is there a way that i can put text boxes in line as you do withe the radio buttons and etc in html?

I am trying to create boxes in line to store auto generated values inside.

Comment: `input` and `textarea` are _"inline"_ by default - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfybpe02/) so it's not clear what you need?

Comment: add your code maybe from a jsfiddle, so we can see what are you doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use:

```
display: inline-block;
```